# Div width expanding

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with a div container being automatically set to the full width of the page, when I actually only want it to expand to fit the contents.  Here's the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<!-- Head -->
<head>
    <title>html_blocked_text</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />   

    <!-- Area for Additional Links -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='html_blocked_text.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
</head>

<!-- Body -->
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class='block'>
            <div class='letter'>S</div>
        </div>
        <div class='block'>
            <div class='letter'>T</div>
        </div>
        <div class='block'>
            <div class='letter'>A</div>
        </div>
        <div class='block'>
            <div class='letter'>Y</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #B8FFDB;
}

#container {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.block {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #003D5C;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.letter {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

and the results (25px and 50px):

[image: 25px for Text Size]
[image: 50px for Text Size]

With the issue being: all the white space after the last letter.  How do I take away the white space on the right side of the last letter?  I only want that container to wrap around the contents (i.e. the letters).

Comment: `#container {display: inline-block;`

Comment: `float:left`, `display:inline`, or `display:inline-block` should get you what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block` to `#container`.

```
#container {display: inline-block;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0sh4uwnf/

Comment: You have won the race. So +1

Comment: @zazu: it's not a race, just a question is so simply to answer that there is more same answers to that :-)

Comment: But you answered first, so means it was a race and you won it :)

Answer (score 3):

you can add `display : inline-block` or `float : left` both of them avoid this problem :

```
#container {
background-color: white;
border-radius: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
float: left;   
}
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8v9qcm60/1/)

Answer (score 2):

`div` is a *block* container so it gets the width of its parent element, in your case the body element which is the full width of the page.

```
#container {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

should give you the desired result